# PHP 7 Type Hinting Issues

Tags: php, types, hint

```
<?php
namespace XYZ\Model;

interface user{
public function getName() : string;
}

?>
```

Now, what happens is that string is assumed to be the type `XYZ\Model\string` and hence, any classes I make implementing the interface don't match up (in different namespaces).

If however I do a `\string`, the code fails with `Scalar type declaration must be unqualified`.

Besides, how many types of boolean can there be? After removing some hints, I got: `Return value of xxxxx::save() must be an instance of boolean, boolean returned in xxxxxx.php:41`

Comment: Are you using PHP7 or HHVM? [Demo](https://3v4l.org/pep1l)

Comment: Please change your question from `string` type declaration to `boolean`. Then this will be helpful to other users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPDATE: Everything's alright with PHP. it's boolean that doesn't support scalar type hinting.

Comment: It's [bool](https://3v4l.org/aVlML), not boolean. And why then for crying out loud did you use `string` in your example ;-)

Comment: You should include a quote from the corresponding documentation section “Warning. Aliases for the above scalar types…”

Answer (score 2):

Tested out the following [Code on 7.0.3](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/992eb2f94ffdeb82b56d7de8a83f2fc5e19991b2) and it works fine, bearing in mind I added a missing `;` next to your namespace definition.

```
namespace XYZ\Model;

interface user {
    public function getName(): string;
}


class Test implements User {
    public function getName(): string {
        return 'SomeName';
    }
}

$t = new Test;
echo $t->getName();
```

**Outputs:**

> SomeName

Comment: Please use a different namespace for the class and you shall see what bothers me.

Comment: "Please use a different namespace for the class" - like so: https://3v4l.org/GZlLV ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, BTW. My original code uses booleans and those aren't supported for scalar type hints, hence the issue.